# Dynamic Nested Relative layout in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-relativelayout

I want to create a layout to browse for category and subcategory that looks like:

[image]

This is for Category and I made this by write .axml in layout that looks fine. Now, when user click category same looks should be generated on its click and it is creating dynamically but child content overlap to parent content and look like this:

[image]

To make a child relative layout I write the below code:

```
RelativeLayout childTaxonomylayout = new RelativeLayout( this );
childTaxonomylayout.Id = Convert.ToInt32( data.Value.Id );
childTaxonomylayout.SetOnClickListener( this );
var param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent );
param.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
param.AddRule( LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft );
childTaxonomylayout.LayoutParameters = param;


TextView textViewChild = new TextView( this );
textViewChild.Text = data.Value.Item.Name;
textViewChild.SetPadding( 20, 10, 0, 10 );
textViewChild.Id = Convert.ToInt32( data.Value.Id );

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent );
rlp2.AddRule( LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom );
rlp2.AddRule( LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft );
textViewChild.LayoutParameters = rlp2;

childTaxonomylayout.AddView( textViewChild );
if (data.Value.Children.Count != 0) {
    var _imgViewClose = new ImageView( this );
    _imgViewClose.Id = Convert.ToInt32( "123" + data.Value.Id.ToString() );
    _imgViewClose.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.ic_right );

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 20 );
    rlp1.AddRule( LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom );
    rlp1.AddRule( LayoutRules.AlignParentRight );
    childTaxonomylayout.AddView( _imgViewClose );
}

childLayout.AddView( childTaxonomylayout );
```

Please let me know what should I change to make my UI correct. Thankyou

Comment: Yes dear, I have also achieved this but by changing in Layout. When I took Nested Linear Layout in place of  Relative and Place Text and Image into one more Linear Layout horizontal , whole design got correct. Are you thinking like that ?

Answer (score 3):

You should try [Expandable ListView](https://github.com/away168/ExpandableListView). I'd strongly recommend to use this because it is inbuilt control and it has the same feature you require beside this if you go with `RelativeLayout` you have to manage many scenario e.g. resolution, items inside, event handling; while using `Expandable ListView` you'd just pass items hierarchy and you done with UI.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it but I am not allow to use third party packages. Can any one suggest me to correct anything in my code?

Comment: No issue, But this is not third party; Its an android native control like normal ListView.

Comment: It will work for N level hierarchy ? My code is support N level hierarchy and runs fine. But It works when I make it as nested Linear Layout. I need to add image to indicate close or open hierarchy. So, I took a image with my text and convert it into Relative and stuck into this situation